# Possible to execute Java Maven Project in MS TFS?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tfs, webdriver

Possible to execute Java Maven Project in MS TFS?

1. I have linked the project inside MS TFS using the POM file but it dosnt seem to open any browser(s) instances.
2. My POM file has a surefire pluging used to execute the TestNG xml but that dosnt seem to work,
3. The tests run too quickly and the results are inconsitent, is this even possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's your TFS server version? And which build system you'd like to use? XAML or vNext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your build server to make life easier. The easiest way to create a build definition for a Maven build is to use Eclipse with the TFS plugin. You connect to your project, create a new build definition, choose Maven, and it will construct a TFSBuild.proj file (yes, the really old Upgrade Template). At the very bottom of that tfsbuild.proj file, you'll need to edit to look something like this:

[image: TFSBuild.proj file edit]

Note the "Goals" entry - this can be modified to your specific goal.

In the build definition, the Configuration Folder Path will have the value of the location of your TFSBuild.Proj file - just the folder. By default, it will be created in $/YourProject/TeamBuildTypes/YourBuildName. In Source Settings, the location of the POM file is mapped to $(SourceDir).

Comment: thanks for your help, with the above code is it possible to target the POM file and in turn target a sole TestNG.xml execution file? i know this setup working within jenkins thanks again

Comment: I know that my guys are running tests, and I think they're triggered from the POM file, as you suggest.

Comment: I've verified that's the way they're doing it. It's a plugin entry in the pom.xml file.

Comment: thanks again for you help i really appreciate it, so if im not mistaken, i need to add the above code to TFSBuild.proj which in turn will target our POM.xml file? thanks Jim

Comment: If it helped, I'd appreciate the vote for an answer. :)

Comment: i havent tried it yet :( but your help has been great, you get my vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the TFS2015 or later with vNext build system, you can refer to this link for detailed steps: [Build your Java app with Maven](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/java-maven).